# Enforce NTP Time Sync on boot - raspberrypi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, ntp, raspbian-wheezy

I have a setup a raspberrypi to sync time from a NTP server as it does not have a HW clock on it, however this update does not happen immediately and takes a while (~15 mins). Is there a way I can enforce the NTP Client to sync datetime with the NTP server before starting up other user processes. If anyone has been able to achieve this please let me know. cheers!

**Update:** The rPi does not have internet connectivity

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this service from the NIST:
[NIST Internet Time Service](https://www.nist.gov/pml/time-and-frequency-division/services/internet-time-service-its).  They have a [list of servers here.](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi) and tips on how to engage with their system from Windows, OSX, and Linux.   The response might be quick enough to hold you over until your NTP client can receive its response.

Comment: forgot to mention.. the rPi does not have a internet connectivity.

Comment: Do you have the NTP service enabled and running?

Comment: @RamanSailopal as mentioned in my question, the NTP service is up and running and syncs the time but only after ~30 minutes. My requirement is to force sync the time on boot to ensure my process starts up with the current time.